# Python list-comprehension: replace function with another using only one line of code

Tags: python, list-comprehension

Please this `function`:

```
def foo(string):
    for char in string:
        if char != 'h' and char != 'a':
            return False
    return True
```

So i want to write this `function` in one line and this is what i have try:

```
def foo(string):
    return [True if 'a' or 'h' in x else False for x in string]
```

Comment: What is the function trying to do?

Comment: Replacing that function with a list comprehension makes no sense - you don't actually want the list. Most likely you want `all` with a *generator expression*.

Comment: Check if the given string contains only 'a' or 'h'

Comment: I just want to write this function in one line

Comment: Tip: look at what your function returns (the second one) and try to find a connection between that and what you want it to return. You'll find that the output of the function should be `True` when all the elements of the list are `True`. In that case use the python builtin `all`. Edit: I don't think your current function does what you think it does (mainly the `'a' or 'h' in x` part) so this advise wouldn't be very helpful.

Answer (score 4):

Your function checks whether the string consists of only the characters `'a'` and `'h'`, so it can be replaced with a test to see whether the set of its characters is a subset of `{'a', 'h'}`.

```py
def foo(string):
    return set(string) <= {'a', 'h'}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your one liner does not what you think it does.

let's decompose your function:

```
[x for x in string]
```

will return a list of strings:

```
>>> string = "aoeu"
>>> [x for x in string]
['a', 'o', 'e', 'u']
```

so then you apply:

```
if 'a' or 'h' in x
```

for each `x` in the above list, let's decompose that:

```
>>> slist = [x for x in string]
>>> 'a' or 'h' in slist[0]
'a'
```

Here what you do is check if `'a'` exists (and it does and always will be) or check if `'h'` is within the single char string `slist[0]`. Though the second part never gets valued, as `'a'` is always there.

So to fix this you want:

```
>>> 'a' == slist[0] or 'h' in slist[0]
True
```

or more concise:

```
>>> slist[0] in ['a', 'h']
True
```

So to rebuild your one-liner:

```
>>> [True if c in ['a', 'h'] else False for c in string]
[True, False, False, False]
```

But as you see, that returns a list, so you want to have one value in the end

```
>>> any([True if c in ['a', 'h'] else False for c in string])
True
```

So your function would be:

```
def foo(string):
    return any([True if c in ['a', 'h'] else False for c in string])
```

So now, what we've built is a function that says whether there's a 'a' or 'h' in the string. In a long and complex way, that could be rewritten:

```
def foo(string):
    return "a" in string or "b" in string
```

But... that's not what your first function does!

```
def foo(string):
    for char in string:
        if char != 'h' and char != 'a':
            return False
    return True
```

that one checks whether the string is *only made* of 'a' or 'h'.

so the best way is to turn your string into a set, to see all the different characters it contains, and return whether that set equal to the set of only 'a' and 'h'.

Others have been faster than me to come up with the solution, so here it goes:

```
def foo(string):
    return set(string) <= {'a', 'h'}
```

thanks to @kaya3 which gave the most elegant solution ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use sets to see if  string contains anything other than 'a' or 'h'

`return not (set(string) - {'a', 'h'})`